# create a new object from two different objects in js

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object, angular-dynamic-forms

I'm struggling with the following task.

On the one hand I have the following object:

```
[
  {
    name: "VALUE1",
    type: "select",
    label: "Label"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE2",
    type: "select",
    label: "Label"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE3",
    type: "select",
    label: "Label"
  },
];
```

On the other hand I have some content for the object above, with I want to merge in a new object.
Here's the content:

```
[
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT",
  }
]
```

**Please notice that the key from the second object matches with the value from the first**
At the end I need a object which should have the following structure:

```
[
  {
    name: 'VALUE1'
    id: 'CONTENT 1 ',
    label: 'LABEL 1',
    type: 'select'
    selectMenuOptions: {
      VALUE1: "CONTENT",
      VALUE1: "CONTENT",
      VALUE1: "CONTENT",
      VALUE1: "CONTENT",
      VALUE1: "CONTENT",
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'VALUE2'
    id: 'CONTENT 2 ',
    label: 'LABEL 2',
    type: 'select'
    selectMenuOptions: {
      VALUE2: "CONTENT",
      VALUE2: "CONTENT",
      VALUE2: "CONTENT",
      VALUE2: "CONTENT",
      VALUE2: "CONTENT",
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'VALUE3'
    id: 'CONTENT 3 ',
    label: 'LABEL 3',
    type: 'select'
    selectMenuOptions: {
      VALUE3: "CONTENT",
      VALUE3: "CONTENT",
      VALUE3: "CONTENT",
      VALUE3: "CONTENT",
      VALUE3: "CONTENT",
    }
  },
]
```

Some background information if it helps:

- Angular 14
- The object I try to form is for dynamic forms

Comment: Instead of writing full sentences in your example result, please show the *actual* result you are expecting. It seems like your second array is missing some properties as well. You can include comments for clarity if needed.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton thx a lot, I make a big mistake on my question. I edited now

Comment: You say you've been struggling, but provide no code showing your struggles. It could be you're 90% of the way there and just need to know a simple trick to get you where you need to be. It would be better if you would provide your attempts so that answerers didn't have to start from scratch and do all your work for you.

Comment: @kayza how should the id be generated? Is it based on index in the array, or are you parsing the number from one of the strings?

Comment: @kayza do you actually want the label to change, or is that just a typo?

Comment: @kayza the result you gave is also impossible since you have duplicate keys

Comment: @ChrisHamilton the id get I from the the content in the second object.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton the relationship is built using the keys of the second object and the values of the first object

Comment: @ChrisHamilton this is the answer for: the result you gave is also impossible since you have duplicate keys

oh, that's right, that's a logical error i have to clarify. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these arrays:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: "VALUE1",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL1"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE2",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL2"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE3",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL3"
  },
];
```

```js
const arr2 = [
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT01",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT02",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT03",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT04",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT05",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT11",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT12",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT13",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT14",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT15",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT21",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT22",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT23",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT24",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT25",
  }
]
```

You can merge them like so:

```js
function merge() {
  const map = new Map<string, string[]>();
  for (const obj of arr2) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      if (!map.get(key)) map.set(key, []);
      map.get(key).push(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  for (const obj of arr1) {
    obj['selectMenuOptions'] = map.get(obj.name) || [];
  }
}
```

Which causes arr1 to look like this:

```js
[
  {
    name: 'VALUE1',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'LABEL1',
    selectMenuOptions: ['CONTENT01', 'CONTENT11', 'CONTENT21'],
  },
  {
    name: 'VALUE2',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'LABEL2',
    selectMenuOptions: ['CONTENT02', 'CONTENT12', 'CONTENT22'],
  },
  {
    name: 'VALUE3',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'LABEL3',
    selectMenuOptions: ['CONTENT03', 'CONTENT13', 'CONTENT23'],
  },
]
```

---

I've excluded `id` since you haven't provided any information on how to generate the id, and presumably `name` is unique, so it should function as an id.

Also, you can't have an object like:

```js
const obj = {
  VALUE1: 'CONTENT1',
  VALUE1: 'CONTENT2',
  VALUE1: 'CONTENT3',
}
```

What would `obj.VALUE1` return in this case?

So I made `selectMenuOptions` an array instead.

---

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-txtmnf?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

it is not very clear what data structure you wish to have.
I will put you a simple example of a "merge" of this data, inspired by this you should be able to get to your goal.

```
const a = [
  {
    name: "VALUE1",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL 1"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE2",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL 2"
  },
  {
    name: "VALUE3",
    type: "select",
    label: "LABEL 3"
  },
]
const b = [
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT 1",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT 2",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT 3",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT 4",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT 5",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT 1",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT 2",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT 3",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT 4",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT 5",
  },
  {
    VALUE1: "CONTENT 1",
    VALUE2: "CONTENT 2",
    VALUE3: "CONTENT 3",
    VALUE4: "CONTENT 4",
    VALUE5: "CONTENT 5",
  }
]

const merged = a.map(element => {
  element.selectMenuOptions = b.map(be => ({ [element.name]: be[element.name] }))
  return element
});
```

Comment: thx, for your answer. But i make a mistake on my question and edited now. I hope now it's clearer to understand my struggle.

Comment: Ok i edit my answer, i think now it's ok for your goal.

Comment: thank you a lot, this helps me for now.
in this case I have the problem, that I have all the `element.name` in a single object. this should be fixed. but the bigger problem is, that all the keys are the same, but this is was my mess, not yours. A logical problem, that I didn't see. thank you again